# I want to stop my sago palms from growing taller

Tags: plant-care

I have a mixture of male and female cycads in my gardens. I want to know how to stop them from growing taller, they are about 10 years older than when they were planted by previous house owner. If I remove the male pollen pod or the female seed pod before they develop will it kill the plant or stunt the growth? I live in Port Macquarie, NSW, on the east coast of Australia.[image]